# Error in calculation for upper limit of foreach range

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw a dashed, shaped arrow.  In order to do this, I'm working on a tikz macro.

The routine works by drawing the arrow, then drawing some white filled rectangles on top of the arrow.

I want to be able to handle arrows of various lengths, so I want to calculate the number and spacing of the white rectangles based on the length.

The code works just fine when I have a number for the upper limit.  But when I have a calculation for the upper limit, I get "Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored".

I would welcome any help that can be provided.  Below is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\def\w{2.5}
\def\d{.25}
\def\lt{12}
\def\la{6}
\def\s{.25}
\def\l{50}
\def\sw{1.5}
\def\dw{.65}
\def\sw{1.5}
\def\dw{.65}
\def\nd{int((\l-2*\la)/(\sw+\dw)) }
\def\intervals{\pgfmathparse{\nd}\pgfmathresult }
\def\offs{(\l-2*\la)/\nd}
\def\limit{\intervals-1}
%\def\limit{16}  % Uncomment this to see the picture I want


\draw [color=green,fill=green]
  (0,0) -- (\la+\d/2,\w/2)
  .. controls (\la+\d/4,3*\w/8) .. (\la,\s)
  .. controls (\l/2-\lt, \s) .. (\l/2,\w/2)
  .. controls (\l/2+\lt, \s) .. (\l-\la,\s)
  .. controls (\l-\la-\d/4,3*\w/8) ..(\l-\la-\d/2, \w/2)
  -- (\l,0)
  -- (\l-\la-\d/2, - \w/2)
   .. controls (\l-\la-\d/4,-3*\w/8) .. (\l-\la,-\s)
   .. controls (\l/2+\lt, -\s) .. (\l/2,-\w/2)
   .. controls (\l/2-\lt,  -\s) .. (\la,-\s)
   .. controls (\la+\d/4,-3*\w/8) .. (\la,-\w/2)
   -- cycle;

  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\limit} {
    \fill[color=white] ( {\la+\offs*(.5+\i)-\dw/2}, {-\w/2} ) 
          rectangle ({\la+\offs*(.5+\i)+\dw/2} , \w/2 );
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: foreach doesn't parse math in the limit expressions. Use `\number\numexpr\intervals-1\relax`

Comment: I tried this, but then got "Missing number, treated as zero".  I had tried this earlier based on some other SX answers.

Comment: It's because `\def\intervals{\pgfmathparse{\nd}\pgfmathresult }` is not appropriate. IT doesn't store the result it stores the code

Comment: `\number\numexpr\nd-1\relax ` also gives "Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: Same problem. It has to hold a number not an expression

Comment: So the `@pgfmathsetmacro` is what is used to convert an expression to a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `\pgfmathsetmacro{<macro>}{<expression>}` if you want to store the evaluated result of an `<expression>` in a `<macro>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
\def\w{2.5}
\def\d{.25}
\def\lt{12}
\def\la{6}
\def\s{.25}
\def\l{50}
\def\sw{1.5}
\def\dw{.65}
\def\sw{1.5}
\def\dw{.65}
\def\nd{int((\l-2*\la)/(\sw+\dw)) }
\pgfmathsetmacro{\intervals}{\nd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\offs}{(\l-2*\la)/\nd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\limit}{\intervals-1}

\draw [color=green,fill=green]
  (0,0) -- (\la+\d/2,\w/2)
  .. controls (\la+\d/4,3*\w/8) .. (\la,\s)
  .. controls (\l/2-\lt, \s) .. (\l/2,\w/2)
  .. controls (\l/2+\lt, \s) .. (\l-\la,\s)
  .. controls (\l-\la-\d/4,3*\w/8) ..(\l-\la-\d/2, \w/2)
  -- (\l,0)
  -- (\l-\la-\d/2, - \w/2)
   .. controls (\l-\la-\d/4,-3*\w/8) .. (\l-\la,-\s)
   .. controls (\l/2+\lt, -\s) .. (\l/2,-\w/2)
   .. controls (\l/2-\lt,  -\s) .. (\la,-\s)
   .. controls (\la+\d/4,-3*\w/8) .. (\la,-\w/2)
   -- cycle;

  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\limit} {
    \fill[color=white] ( {\la+\offs*(.5+\i)-\dw/2}, {-\w/2} ) 
          rectangle ({\la+\offs*(.5+\i)+\dw/2} , \w/2 );
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Werner.  I had not used \pgfmathsetmacro before.  It works well.